# Can OCS Inventory installed on the host get the list of softwares installed on a Virtual Machine?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Suppose OCS Inventory is installed on a Windows host to inventoriate installed programs, but there is at least one Virtual Machine installed, like Oracle VM Virtual Box, with a guest OS, let's say, another Windows.

1. OCS Inventory, by default, is able to see inside the Virtual Machine as well, since it is running on the Windows host?
2. Is a special plugin needed to enable this ability?
3. Or OCS Inventory could only inventoriate Virtual Machine programs if it is also installed on the Virtual Machines themselves?

Comment: Ask your Company or OCS Support.   Otherwise off topic here

Comment: @John How could this be off-topic? On which Stack Exchange website it could be on-topic?

Comment: Your workplace is a Company environment (so it seems to me) and Corporate issues need to be addressed to the company support people.

Comment: @John The question is about a publicly released software. It was not created by this company nor is owned exclusively by it. So it seems anyone is apt to reply. Also, the infrastructure people is not going to answer questions about themselves.

Comment: If I have misinterpreted  "When OCS Inventory is implanted on a workplace" my apologies, but you should perhaps clarify your question as I am not the only person who misinterpreted.

Comment: @John My mistake, sorry. The question was terribly poor written. Edited already.

Comment: What OCS Software? Did you check its documentation? This is heavily dependent on the implementation. In most cases the easiest is probably to install it on the VM as well.

Comment: I'd say false, n/a, true. I'm not familiar with this kind of corporate stuff, but it sounds to me what the client would do is probably scanning the hard drive (or maybe registry, on Windows).